# Doctrine schema update/migration error: unique index

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, migration

I've found similar questions but they were in the app, mine relates to the cli commands, i.e. `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force` or `php app/console doctrine:migrations:migrate`

Error:

```
Migration 20130112151503 failed during Execution. Error An exception occurred wh
ile executing 'CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_68D3801E989D9B62 ON artists (slug)':



    SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '' for key
     'UNIQ_68D3801E989D9B62'




  [Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException]
  An exception occurred while executing 'CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_68D3801E989
  D9B62 ON artists (slug)':

  SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '' fo
  r key 'UNIQ_68D3801E989D9B62'
```

I was really hoping that migrations would take care of this error, but alas. How do I resolve this issue, e.g. I would only be able to run the migrations command on the live server. Why doesn't the migration first drop the unique index if exists? Or why doesn't it detect there is already an unique index?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That SQL error isn't saying there is already a unique index, it's saying that the slug column has duplicate values and it can't add the index because of it.

Ensure that the slug column only has unique (or null, but probably not recommended for a slug column) values, and then try to run the migration again.

Comment: Ah, I see. It's null, I'll change it

Comment: @Mike, did you mean that if I already have database filled with data and I create new column with unique: true I will always get this error? How to then handle migrations which can not be executed on production server?

Comment: Yes, if you attempt to create a unique index on a column that already has duplicate values, you're going to hit an error.  You must resolve all duplicates before attempting to create a unique index.  Your migration will crash if attempting to do otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `slug` field in your database is empty or duplicate. So, try to delete everything in your table and generate again the command